# PL/SQL Procedure on APEX - Issue with initialization

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have created a procedure that is link to APEX to close PO. Currently I have an error message in my message log table when I try to close a PO. The error seems to be with the initialization.

Below is the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APEX_EBS_EXTENSION.CLOSE_PO (P_FILE_NAME IN 

VARCHAR2)
as
x_action constant varchar2(20) := 'CLOSE'; 
x_calling_mode constant varchar2(2) := 'PO';
x_conc_flag constant varchar2(1) := 'N';
x_return_code_h varchar2(100);
x_auto_close constant varchar2(1) := 'N';
vn_user_id NUMBER ;
vn_resp_id NUMBER :=51058 ;
vn_app_id  NUMBER :=201;
x_origin_doc_id number;
x_returned boolean;
--PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

vr_message_detail MESSAGE_LOG%rowtype ;

vc_message varchar2(4000);




CURSOR c_po_details IS
SELECT XPTS.ORGANISATION_ID, XPTS.PO_HEADER_ID,XPTS.PO_NUMBER, XPTDS.PO_LINE_ID, XPTS.SHIP_ORGANISATION_ID, XPTS.ITEM_ID
           ,XPTS.DOCUMENT_SUBTYPE, XPTS.DOC_TYPE_CODE, XPTS.TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,XPTS.ID , XPTS.ITEM_NUMBER,XPTS.USER_ID
FROM xx_po_toclose_stg1 XPTS,
     XX_PO_TOCLOSE_DET_STG  XPTDS
WHERE XPTS.SEQ = XPTDS.SEQ_NO
AND XPTS.USER_ID     = V('APP_USER')
and XPTS.filename = P_FILE_NAME ;


--where po_number = '1000327';

begin

/*
select fnd.user_id , 
       fresp.responsibility_id, 
       fresp.application_id  into user_id, resp_id ,resp_appl_id 
from   fnd_user@BI_APPS fnd ,  fnd_responsibility_tl@BI_APPS fresp
where  fnd.user_name = 'SYSADMIN' 
and  fresp.responsibility_name = 'System Administrator'
and fresp.language='US' ;


select fnd.user_id , 
       fresp.responsibility_id, 
       fresp.application_id  into l_user_id, l_resp_id ,l_resp_appl_id 
from   fnd_user@BI_APPS fnd ,  fnd_responsibility_tl@BI_APPS fresp
where  fnd.user_name ='APEX_IR_USER'
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN start_date and NVL(end_date,'31-dec-4712');

   EXCEPTION 
            WHEN OTHERS THEN  
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception');
                l_user_id := -1;
              l_resp_id := -1;
               l_resp_appl_id := -1;

fnd_global.apps_initialize@BI_APPS (user_id => -1,
resp_id => 20866,
resp_appl_id => 101);

*/

vc_message := 'CALLING THE USER ID' ;

  SELECT FND.USER_ID 
       INTO vn_user_id
        FROM FND_USER@BI_APPS FND
         WHERE FND.USER_NAME = 'CLOSEPO_USER' ;



/*
--working
fnd_global.apps_initialize@BI_APPS (user_id => 5930,
resp_id => 50295,
resp_appl_id => 201);
*/

vc_message := 'PASSING PARAMETERS IN THE VARIABLES' ;
            fnd_global.apps_initialize@BI_APPS(user_id =>2452 ,
                         resp_id =>  50771,
                        resp_appl_id => 201);



vc_message := 'LOOPING' ;

for po_head in c_po_details LOOP

    --mo_global.init@BI_APPS  (po_head.doc_type_code);
    --mo_global.set_policy_context@BI_APPS  ('S', po_head.org_id_po);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Calling PO_Actions.close_po for Closing/Finally Closing po number =>'|| po_head.PO_NUMBER);

    x_returned :=
    po_actions.close_po@BI_APPS (
    p_docid => po_head.po_header_id,
    p_doctyp =>po_head.doc_type_code,
    p_docsubtyp =>po_head.document_subtype,
    p_lineid => po_head.PO_LINE_ID,
    p_shipid => NULL,
    p_action => x_action,
    p_reason => 'Close Purchase Order On'||SYSDATE,
    p_calling_mode => x_calling_mode,
    p_conc_flag => x_conc_flag,
    p_return_code => x_return_code_h,
    p_auto_close => x_auto_close,
    p_action_date => SYSDATE,
    p_origin_doc_id => NULL);

    IF x_returned = TRUE THEN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Item Number which just got Closed/Finally Closed is '||po_head.PO_NUMBER);
    commit;

                        vr_message_detail.message_type := 'E' ;
                        vc_message := vc_message || ' -SqlCode- ' || sqlcode || ' -SqlErrMsg- ' || sqlerrm ;
                        vr_message_detail.message_descr_long := vc_message ;
                        vr_message_detail.message_descr := substr(vc_message, 1, 4000) ;
                        LOG_MESSAGE(vr_message_detail);

vc_message := 'Updating the Remarks Column in xx_po_toclose_stg1 if success' ;

    UPDATE xx_po_toclose_stg1 A
    SET A.REMARKS = 'PO Number' ||'  '||po_head.PO_NUMBER||'  '|| 'with item number '||'  '||po_head.ITEM_NUMBER||'  ' ||'has been closed  by'||'  '||po_head.USER_ID||'  '||'on'||'  '||sysdate
    WHERE A.ID = po_head.ID;

    COMMIT;

    vc_message := 'Updating the STATUS Column in xx_po_toclose_stg1 if success' ;
     --UPDATE STATUS ON FINAL TABLE 
    vc_message := 'Updating the Status Column in xx_po_toclose_stg1 ' ;
    UPDATE xx_po_toclose_stg1 A
    SET A.STATUS = x_action
    WHERE A.ID = po_head.ID;

  COMMIT;



    ELSE

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('API Failed to Close/Finally Close line ');

    vc_message := 'Updating the Remarks Column in xx_po_toclose_stg1 if failure' ;

    UPDATE xx_po_toclose_stg1 A
    SET A.REMARKS = 'API Failed to Close/Finally Close the Item number'
    WHERE A.ID = po_head.ID;
    COMMIT;

     vc_message := 'Updating the STATUS Column in xx_po_toclose_stg1 if failure' ;
     --UPDATE STATUS ON FINAL TABLE 
    vc_message := 'Updating the Status Column in xx_po_toclose_stg1 ' ;
    UPDATE xx_po_toclose_stg1 A
    SET A.STATUS = 'FAILED'
    WHERE A.ID = po_head.ID;

    END IF;





    COMMIT;

END LOOP;


EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN

        vr_message_detail.message_type := 'E' ;
        vc_message := vc_message || ' -SqlCode- ' || sqlcode || ' -SqlErrMsg- ' || sqlerrm ;
        vr_message_detail.message_descr_long := vc_message ;
        vr_message_detail.message_descr := substr(vc_message, 1, 4000) ;
        LOG_MESSAGE(vr_message_detail);


END CLOSE_PO;
/
```

**The error message is "CALLING THE USER ID -SqlCode- 100 -SqlErrMsg- ORA-01403: no data found"**

Below is the section of the procedure that should trigger this message

```
vc_message := 'CALLING THE USER ID' ;

  SELECT FND.USER_ID 
       INTO vn_user_id
        FROM FND_USER@BI_APPS FND
         WHERE FND.USER_NAME = 'CLOSEPO_USER' ;
```

Below is the section for initialization

```
vc_message := 'PASSING PARAMETERS IN THE VARIABLES' ;
            fnd_global.apps_initialize@BI_APPS(user_id =>2452 ,
                         resp_id =>  50771,
                        resp_appl_id => 201);
```

I am using a user id for a user (CLOSEPO_USER) created on the instance. The responsibility id used is for PO.

I would be grateful if anyone can guide me on this issue so that I can debug and resolve this issue.

Comment: This is Oracle eBusiness Suite you're working with - this uses VPD with various conditions, so your session must match the expected values. For example, a common issue is that your session has a different `userenv('LANG')` than is expected by eBus.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01403 means the query returns no results.

Run the query (as your Apex application's parsing schema) in sqlplus or an IDE:

```
SELECT FND.USER_ID 
FROM FND_USER@BI_APPS FND 
WHERE FND.USER_NAME = 'CLOSEPO_USER' ;
```

It probably returns no rows. Fix that and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

This was my first guess but when I executed the query it was returning the correct user id. The query returns one line with user id 2452.

Comment: See @Jeffrey Kemp's comment on your question. VPD might be interfering. Other steps: eliminate everything from the procedure except the `SELECT ... INTO ...`. When the error still occurs, you can be sure that the query returns no rows and causes the no_data_found.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciate your comments.

I managed to solve the issue by adding the piece of code below.

mo_global.init@bi_apps.sunresort.local ('PA');
apps.mo_global.set_policy_context@bi_apps.sunresort.local('S', 401);